# Node.js/geth : executing js creates zombie process and stops , possible resource leak

Tags: javascript, node.js, go-ethereum

I'm running a js code connecting on [web3](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API) package to **JSON RPC API** for geth. The code goes through every transaction of incoming block and skips if its not an internal wallet , if it is then sends the info to another server through http request.

Somehow this code starts spawning lots of zombie processes and when the count reaches exactly 2040 its stopping the processes stays alive but the log is stopping essentially meaning the code is not executing. Even though I'm not able to find which exact line in the code is creating the extra processes, I have a question --> These are defunct processes so they have exited but how come they holding resources or aren't they ? If not then why is it stopping exactly at that 2040 number, also is there a possibility that callback functions might create zombies

the code uses **eth.filter.watch** function, which is not closed because it has to continuously gather block info..

this is my top
[image]

this is my free -h
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found the solution for this. Apparently, there was a callback function that wasn't properly handled thus creating a leak. When the ram got full of processes that it can handle, its just stopping at that number. When I changed to code to return the call back in the right way, it worked.